# subtract two column from different table and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

after one week search i couldn't write this query please help me.
i have 3 table **purchase**, **selles**, **stuff**.
i want to first sum *purchase.quantity* *selles.quantity* fields separately and then subtract these two column *purchase.quantity selles.quantity* then GROUP BY purchase.scale, stuff.name

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

i have these 3 table

```
table purchase:
   'id', 'invoice_id', 'stuff_id', 'quantity', 'scale', 'price'
table selles:
   'id', 'selles_invoice_num', 'stuff_id', 'quantity', 'scale', 'price'
table stuff:
   'id', 'name'
```

---

i have this query but result (quantities) is wrong

```
SELECT sum(purchase.quantity) - sum(selles.quantity) as quantities, 
       purchase.scale, 
       stuff.name , 
       stuff.id 
FROM purchase, 
     selles, 
     stuff 
where purchase.stuff_id = selles.stuff_id 
and purchase.scale = selles.scale 
and purchase.stuff_id = stuff.id 
group by purchase.scale, 
         stuff.name 
ORDER BY stuff.name , 
         purchase.scale
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean about 'result (quantities) is wrong'?

Comment: Add some sample data (not too much, not too little), the current result and the expected result.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." (Older MySQL don't care about this, but may return an unpredictable result. Newer MySQL versions are stricter.)

Comment: please see screenshots i uploaded from all three table in order  purchase , selles , stuff

Comment: please look updates (table data)

Comment: I can't get those scale columns. Neither as join condition, nor as select item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with inner join

```
        SELECT sum(pur.psum) - sum(sca.ssum) as quantities, p.scale, st.name , st.id FROM
 stuff st INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT sum(p.quantity) as psum,p.scale,p.stuff_id  FROM purchase p GROUP BY p.scale,p.stuff_id) pur 
on pur.stuff_id = st.id  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT sum(s.quantity) as ssum,s.scale,s.stuff_id  FROM scale s GROUP BY s.scale,s.stuff_id) sca
 on sca.scale=pur.scale and sca.stuff_id=pur.stuff_id  group by pur.scale, st.name ORDER BY st.name , pur.scale;
```

Comment: can you try this and let me know

Comment: your query return the same previews result :(

Comment: see my tables screenshots data please

Comment: tnx a bunch i am waiting for your answer

Comment: just please wait tnxxx

Comment: YESSSSS it work tnx a bunch mr  Mahesh Madushanka 
i dont know how to say tnx for your best help 
tnx tnx tnx